# Get browser to unzip a gzipped http response

Tags: javascript, browser, gzip, static-site

Is there a way I can force a browser to unzip an http response?  I'm just trying to fetch prezipped files (.e.g foo.json.gz) from a simple server.

I want this:

```
fetch("foo.json.gz").then(x => x.json()).then(unzipped_data => ...)
```

All my hosted files are prezipped, and I just want to use a basic static server.  i.e. I don't want to setup a fancy server that knows how to send the files over with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: The most basic server you can possibly use will be able to add a header indicating the encoding, maybe even automatically. This is needed even for HTML. Browsers will decompress the responses much faster than you could even dream of doing with a JavaScript gzip implementation.